# A* Search Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, a-star

I would like to have something clarified with regards to the following A* Search example:

[image: A* Search Example]

The sections highlighted with the red ellipses are the areas that I do not understand; it appears that `{S,B} f=2+6=8` has been taken/moved/copied from `Expand S` (above) and used in `Expand A`.  It also appears that `{S,A,X} f=(1+4)+5=10` has been taken/moved/copied from `Expand A` and used in `Expand B`.

Could somebody kindly explain why this happens?  I am able to read the graph perfectly well and do not have any trouble interpreting it - it is merely the fact that I do not know **why** the aforementioned paths/routes have been duplicated elsewhere.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is taking the current best item, removing it, and replacing it with the expansion (inserting the new items into appropriate positions in the list).  Think of it like this:

Expand S:

- **`{S,A} f = 1+5 = 6`**
- **`{S,B} f = 2+6 = 8`**

Expand A:

- <del>`{S,A} f = 1+5 = 6`</del>
- `{S,B} f = 2+6 = 8`
- **`{S,A,X} f = (1+4)+5 = 10`**
- **`{S,A,Y} f = (1+7)+8 = 16`**

Expand B:

- <del>`{S,B} f = 2+6 = 8`</del>
- `{S,A,X} f = (1+4)+5 = 10`
- **`{S,B,C} f = (2+7)+4 = 13`**
- `{S,A,Y} f = (1+7)+8 = 16`
- **`{S,B,D} f = (2+1)+15 = 18`**

Comment: Sir i am new to artificial intelligence and in context to this diagram i have a doubt that here * A* needed to compute all the possible paths.* then how come is it useful ?
and in *Rich and knight* its mentioned that h' should not overestimate h, and in wikipedia its written that the estimated cost (h') must always be less that than or equal to the actual cost of reaching the goal. So, this means we have to compute all the possible paths beforehand? is that so ? or am i missing anything. Would be great help Sir.

Answer (score 2):

The paths are not duplicated, they simply remain as paths that the algorithm hasn't explored yet. A* works by maintaining an *open set*, it is the collection of nodes the algorithm knows already how to reach (and by what cost), but it hasn't tried expanding them yet.

At each iteration the algorithm chooses a node to expand from the open set (the one with the lowest f function - the f function is the sum of the cost the algorithm already knows it takes to get to the node (g) and the the algorithm's estimate of how much it will cost to get from the node to the goal (h, the heuristic).

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm)

look at the pseudo-code there, as you can see the open set is used. So bottom line - it's not that the algorithm works by duplicating\copying\moving paths or nodes from one iteration to another - it simply does its work on the same collection of nodes (of course nodes do get added and removed from the collection).

Hope this helps...