# A* algorithm on a directed graph

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, a-star

Hello Can anyone help me understand how the A* algorithm works on this graph?

[image]

I want to find the lowest cost path from 1 to 7.

Here is how I solved the problem:
 From 1 -> 7:

```
{1,2}f = 2+7=9
 {1,3}f = 11+0=11
 {1,4}f = 1+11=12
```

EXPAND 2

```
{1,3}f = 11+0=11
 {1,4}f = 1+11=12
 {1,2,5}f = (2+3)+5=10
```

EXPAND 5

```
{1,3}f = 11+0=11
 {1,4}f = 1+11=12
 {1,2,5,3}f = (2+3+5)+0=10
 {1,2,5,7}f = (2+3+7)+0=12
```

EXPAND 3

```
{1,3}f = 11+0=11
 {1,4}f = 1+11=12
 {1,2,5,7}f = (2+3+7)+0=12
 {1,2,5,3,7}f = (2+3+5+1)+0 = 11
 {1,2,5,3,6}f = (2+3+5+1)+1=12
```

So the correct answer is `{1,2,5,3,7}f = (2+3+5+1)+0 = 11`. Am I write?

Comment: Technically, since `{1,3}` and `{1,2,5,3,7}` both have the same cost in the last step you should check the paths `{1,3,6}` and `{1,3,7}` because they could end up with the same cost as `{1,2,5,3,7}`. In some graphs you might end up with multiple paths of the same cost.

Comment: But they don't :). And if there would be multiple paths of the same cost which one is being considered?

Comment: `But they don't` - But you only know that because you expanded those paths and found their cost was greater. :) As for which path to choose from multiple paths, you can take all of them, the first one, the last one, a random one, the one with fewest edges, the one with the most edges, the one with the most northerly edges... In other words, it depends entirely on the problem you're trying to solve and  your preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the numbers in the brackets are the estimated distances from a given node to the goal using some heuristic (at first glance they seem to be consistent with an admissible heuristic function). If this is the case, then this is the *h(x)* in the cost equation:

> *f(x)* = *g(x)* + *h(x)*

*g(x)* would be the *actual* cost of the path from the source to node *x*. Starting from node 1, we have 3 outgoing edges: 2, 3 and 4.

> *f(2)* = *g(2)* + *h(2)*
>   *f(3)* = *g(3)* + *h(3)*
>   *f(4)* = *g(4)* + *h(4)*

Filling in the numbers from your graph we get:

> *f(2)* = 2 + 7 = 9
>   *f(3)* = 11 + 0 = 11
>   *f(4)* = 1 + 11 = 12

*f(2)* is the lowest cost, so we choose node 2. The next step isn't very instructive (since we can only go to node 5) except to note that *g(x)* is the actual cost to reach node *x* **from the source node**, that is, the cost of edge 1->2 plus the cost of edge 2->5:

> *g(5)* = 2 + 3 = 5

And from there *g(3)* and *g(7)* will add their edge costs to *g(5)*. Hopefully you see how this is going now and can complete the path.

#### Edit:

There is some confusion about he example in [A* Search Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849667/a-search-algorithm). I'll try to translate between the notation used there and what I've used.

Take as an example the decision to be made in the other question where we have chosen the path from S to A. We must either continue the path to node X or Y. They show:

> {S,A,X} *f* = (1+4)+5=10
>   {S,A,Y} *f* = (1+7)+8=16

In the notation that I've been using, this is equivalent to:

> *f(X)* = (1+4)+5=10, where *g(X)* = (1+4) and *h(X)* = 5
>   *f(Y)* = (1+7)+8=16, where *g(Y)* = (1+7) and *h(Y)* = 8

As you can see in both cases, when you are trying to decide what node to select next (X or Y), you have to add the actual cost of reaching that node, g(x), to the estimated cost of going from that node to the goal, h(x).

Comment: On g(5) should't we add the estimated distance for 5? And so g(5) = (2+3)+5 = 10? This is how I saw in an exaple there was added the cost of the edges involved plus the estimated distance of that node. Which one is correct? I'm confused...

Comment: Plese tell me which is the correct way to do it..

Comment: *g(x)* does not include estimates of anything; it is the **actual** length of the path taken to get to node *x*. (*h(x)* is the estimate for the remainder of the path from node *x* to the goal.) For example, `g(1) = 0` and `g(7)` will be the length of the path found as the final answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849667/a-search-algorithm So this example is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps if you had included this information, what your actual problem was and the previous post that was causing you confusion, this post would never have been closed. I suggest you edit your question with this information and see if it can be re-opened. As to your question, the example appears perfectly correct. I'll have a look at it in a little while and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks now it seems more clear to me

Comment: I have updated the question and provided an answer for the problem. Would you take a look and tell me if it's ok?